# Python BeautifulSoup - find specific <li> in <ul class>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to extract "li" from the following HTML:

[image]

I tried it this way:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
containers = soup.find('div', {'class': 'pagination-container'}).find('ul')`
containers.li
```

but I do not get the expected result.
can anyone help me?

Comment: Post code, not image of code

Answer (score 2):

```
soup.find_all('li')[0]
```

for searching all li on your page, 0 for indexing it.

```
soup.find_all('span', class_='ad')
```

searching for a span with class ad

my span contained lot of data other spans and  which I wanted to get rid of and I knew I am searching for this specific word between  and

```
Artist = soup.find_all('h1')[0]
Artist = re.search('<h1>(.*)<span', str(Artist))
Artist = Artist.group(0)
Artist = str(Artist).replace('<h1>','')
Artist = str(Artist).replace('<span','')
```

I didn't come up with anything better but it worked.. I will be happy for recommendation as well :)